# How to connect to computer on a different network mask over VPN

Tags: vpn

I have a local computer I connect to workplace over VPN. I get assigned an ip address on 255.255.255.255.

Now I want to connect to another computer on subnet 255.255.255.0.

Is this possible over a vpn?

Details are:

IP Address I want to connect to:

10.222.222.1 (Also the DC)

255.255.255.0

IP Address of Virtual Server, hosted my side, client with VPN connection:

192.168.222.33

255.255.255.0

Comment: These are not subnets, these are network masks. Edit your question and provide the actual IP addresses of all your interfaces, and (if you can) network information about the network you want to connect to, plus the network the VPN actually DOES connect you to.

Comment: You need to talk to your workplace network administrators. They will tell you what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I can see what you're getting at user54463, in a nutshell it is possible if the vpn/firewall/router configurations allow it.  Are you in control of the vpn hardware or is that handled by an IT department/person?  If that's the case, you'll have to talk with them on the matter of accessing a specific resource from your VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, all traffic will be routed over the VPN.  You are being assigned a point to point adddress.  It should have a route to another address on the remote network side.  All traffic other that that required by the VPN connection itself should be routed over this address.

The private addresses (such as your DC) that can be accessed will depend on the configuration of the network you are connected to via your VPN connection.  This will depend on the routing and firewall configuration on that end.